# Mark region and insert prefix

Tags: emacs, elisp

I recently switched from vi to emacs, and now I'm porting my most important macros to emacs. What I need most is the ability to prefix a marked region of text with a string, including header and footer:

Original:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

After marking the 2nd and 3rd line, I want emacs to ask me for a number, say 002, and do the following, ideally remembering my choice:

```
line 1
*#002# Start:
*$line 2
*$line 3
*#002# End.
line 4
```

So far, I have managed to insert start and end tags with the following code:

```
(defun comment-region (start end)
  "Insert COBOL comments."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion 
    (goto-char end) (insert "*#xxx# End.\n")
    (goto-char start) (insert "*#xxx# Start:\n")
    ))
```

However, I can't seem to find out how to prefix all lines in the region with `*$` and how to make emacs ask me for a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: `comment-region` is built into Emacs.  You're overwriting a very commonly used function.

Comment: @event_jr: oops, should've checked first. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

I've taken to solving this type of problems by dynamically generating a
snippet with [yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) lately.

Here is the code:

```
(require 'yasnippet)
(defun cobol-comment-region (beg end)
  "comment a region as cobol (lines 2,3 commented)

line 1
*#002# Start:
*$line 2
*$line 3
*#002# End.
line 4
"
  (interactive "*r")
  (setq beg (progn
             (goto-char beg)
             (point-at-bol 1))
       end (progn
             (goto-char end)
             (if (bolp)
                 (point)
               (forward-line 1)
               (if (bolp)
                   (point)
                 (insert "\n")
                 (point)))))
  (let* ((str (replace-regexp-in-string
               "^" "*$" (buffer-substring-no-properties beg (1- end))))
         (template (concat "*#${1:002}# Start:\n"
                           str
                           "\n*#$1# End.\n"))
         (yas-indent-line 'fixed))
    (delete-region beg end)
    (yas-expand-snippet template)))
```

## video included, what???

Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ljg7c2Up20) of it in action:

Answer (score 1):

This is a better approach, but its a little awkward at the end...

```
(defun comment-region (start end prefix)
  "Insert COBOL comments."
  (interactive "r\nsPrefix: ")
  (save-excursion
    (narrow-to-region start end)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (insert "*#" prefix " #Start.\n")
    (while (not (eobp))
      (insert "*$")
      (forward-line))
    (insert "*#" prefix " #End.\n")
    (widen)))
```

Comment: I missed one of the requirements so this answer isn't quite right.  Will fix soon.

Comment: I recommend you use `forward-line` instead of `next-line`+`beginning-of-line`, since `next-line` is sensitive to line-wrapping and other display artifacts.  Also you can use `(not (eobp))`.

Comment: I had forgotten about the next-line/forward-line difference.  And eobp. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use [cobol-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/cobol-mode.el) instead of writing ad hoc functions yourself.

The file header contains detailed instructions on how to use it.

Then just use <kbd>C-x C</kbd> which runs the command `comment-region`, which comments the region according to the major mode (in your case, cobol).

Comment: In general, you are right. However, my company's coding guidelines require some special effort. A COBOL comment is simply denoted by a `*` in column 0.

Comment: @Philip: still it makes more sense to instrument an existing cobol-mode to comply with the special requirements (using, e.g., `defadvice` or just direct code modifications) than to roll out your own major mode.